# Formula for the number of digits in the number $2^x$

Tags: exponentiation

I'm wondering if there is a formula for the number of digits in $2^x$.

For example if $x = 3$ then the number of digits is equal to $1$ because $2^3 = 8$
or for example if $x = 4$ then the number of digits is equal to $2$ because $2^4 = 16$.

In an attempt to solve this problem on my own I made the following table:

```
2^1 = 1
2^2 = 1
2^3 = 1
2^4 = 2
2^5 = 2
2^6 = 2
2^7 = 3
2^8 = 3
2^9 = 3
2^10 = 4
2^11 = 4
2^12 = 4
2^13 = 4
2^14 = 5
```

At first it looks like there is a pattern of threes but then $10$-$13$ ruins it.  It's late and I can't think of any other way to approach this problem, any help would be awesome.

The question is $2^x \ge 100\,000\,000$ digits.

Comment: Use the fact that $\log_{10}2\approx 0.3$

Comment: Actually, $\log_{10}2\approx 0.3$ (which comes from $2^{10}=1024\approx 1000$) does get you quite far because $\log_{10}2\approx 0.30103$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Number of digits in $n$ is given by $1+\lfloor\log_{10}(n) \rfloor$. Hence, in your case, the number of digits in $2^x$ is given by
$$1+\lfloor x \log_{10}2 \rfloor$$
where $\lfloor y \rfloor$ is the greatest integer $\leq y$. For instance, $\lfloor 3.4 \rfloor =3$; $\lfloor 4.1244 \rfloor =4$; $\lfloor -6.0926 \rfloor =-7$;

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question... I'm just taking precalc now but are those bracket things an int function?

Comment: @java Have edited the answer to clarify your question.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B%E2%8C%8Axlog2%E2%8C%8B%3D+100000000

Comment: @java those "bracketed things" is a floor function. It returns integral part of its input.
For example ⌊2.45⌋=2, ⌊-1.23⌋=-2
here's link to wikipedia http://goo.gl/nnYzx